# Rspec Mock_model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to ruby and ruby on rails. How can I stub attributes in a class?

```
class User < PresentationModel
  ...
  attr_accessor  :_vendor
```

_vendor is in my databse and has three columns: ID, shortname, type. How can I only stub this attirbute in rspec?

Something like this?

```
  @vendor = mock_model(vendor, :ID=> 12, :shortname => 'testBLA', :type => 1)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stub this attribute only by:

```
@vendor = mock_model(Vendor, **:id** => 1, :shortname => "Bla", :type => 1)
```

(Attention for the Rails id convention)

And then:

User.should_receive(:_vendor).and_return @vendor

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347880/stubbing-a-model-attribute) too.